# Infinitive clause functioning as what?

Tags: infinitives

> She gifted the man a dog **who** *ought to have been named*.

Is **who** the implicit subject of the infinitive clause (italicized)? If so, what would the infinitive clause function as?

Note: "function" as in how is the clause used - adverbially, adjectivally, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "function as"? Different sources use that term in different ways.

Comment: @alphabet "function as" meaning how is the infinitive clause used - adverbially, adjectivally, etc.

Comment: "Who" is the subject of the relative clause "ought to have been named". The infinitival clause "to have been named" is complement of the matrix verb "ought". Incidentally, the main grammatical functions in a sentence are subject, object, complement and modifier.

Comment: *Ought* is not an infinitive; it’s a modal followed by an infinitive.

Comment: Is there anything written either before or after the sentence you quote which makes clear whether the problem was the dog referred to went to the man intended (presumably because the rightful owner had not been named) or whether the gifted dog had not been named?  Without information about the context of the sentence, I find it hard to understand the question.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It's the opposite! The *to* belongs in the same verb phrase as the following verb, not the preceding one.

Comment: @BillJ If you want to adopt H&P's terminology, surely you should hold that subjects and objects belong within the category of complements (pp. 52-53)?

Comment: @alphabet Who said anything about CGEL? Yes, subjects and objects are sub-types of complement, but we use the former terms, rather than the broader label 'complement', in tree diagrams and when analysing clauses generally.

Comment: @BillJ My point is: I wouldn't say that "the main grammatical functions in a sentence are subject, object, complement, and modifier"; that suggests that the four are mutually exclusive categories.

Comment: That's the CGEL gospel. Don't worry; most linguists don't use it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Negative comments like that are of no use to anyone. FYI, a great many linguists and grammarians use those terms. What other terms could we use for those functions?

Comment: Wake up @alphabet Got better ones? Of course they are distinct functions, what else could they be? Since you apparently have a copy of CGEL, you'll no doubt have noticed that those are the terms it uses throughout. In any case, just about everyone uses them. And if you disagree that the infinitival clause is a complement of "ought", then enlighten us to what it is in your view. Btw, none of this is helping the OP, who is obviously unimportant to you.

Comment: "subject, object, complement, and modifier": OMG, no verb. That really takes the damn cake. {laughing}

Comment: @Tuffy Sorry, but this is just a sentence I made up. I intended the sentence to mean that the dog had not been named yet.

Comment: @anu Fair enough. Are you clear now that the infinitival clause is "to have been named", whose function is that of complement of "ought"? Note that for every verb there is a clause.

Comment: @BillJ Yeah, I can see that

Comment: @anu  In that case, it would be more usual to use a comma after the word 'dog'.  'Who' is the subject of the main verb in the subordinate relative clause "who ought ... named."  so 'who' is subject to the verb 'ought'.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Cambridge dictionary, the OP's sentence doesn't contain an infinitive clause: "ought to" is a semi-modal verb. The infinitive "to have" isn't present.

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ought-to

"Ought to is a semi-modal verb because it is in some ways like a modal verb and in some ways like a main verb. For example, unlike modal verbs, it is followed by to, but like modal verbs, it does not change form for person:

I ought to phone my parents.

It ought to be easy now.

The main verbs used to express modal meanings:

Core modal verbs: can, could, may, might, will, shall, would, should, must

Semi-modals: dare, need, ought to, used to

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/modal-verbs-and-modality

The OP's original sentence: She gifted the man a dog who ought to have been named.

If you replace the "ought to" with another modal, say "should," the sentence would read, He gifted the man a dog who should have been named. "who should have been named" is clearly a relative clause modifying dog ("functioning" as an adjective). The relative clause is in the present perfect passive, so the subject (who) receives the action. Yes, there should have been a comma before the relative clause. The use of "ought to" instead of another modal doesn't change any of the above.

Comment: The modal verb is just "ought". The "to" is a subordinator introducing the following infinitival clause "to have been named".

Comment: One could write '_ought to_ **is** a semi-modal verb' and cite an authority in support (admittedly less reliable on grammar than CGEL) but quoting one authority as indisputable is hardly within the spirit of the site. And especially when it's considered so unchallengeable that it doesn't even need an attribution.

Comment: A comma before the relative clause? Why?

Comment: @Lambie I read it as a nonrestrictive relative clause.

Comment: Replacing "ought to" with "should" makes it an infinitive clause?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Pointless comment. Who's talking about CGEL? Zan 700 doesn't mention it. The "to" is always a subordinator, a special marker for VPs of infinitival clauses.

Comment: @BillJ Since a reference that is recommended as authoritative by ELU states that 'ought to'_is_ a semi-modal verb, saying it's not, without a reference to support this opposite analysis, is going against the spirit of the site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What authoritative reference? The golden rule is that we don't use dictionaries for grammar. The modal verb is just "ought". To claim that the subordinator "to" is part of the preceding verb (thus "ought to") is a ridiculous mistake. A reference is hardly needed for something that is as clear as day.

Comment: @BillJ If it's as clear as day, it doesn't belong on ELU and should not be addressed. If it's considered worthy of some response, ELU expects supporting references to be included, and alternative analyses at least to be acknowledged (if then refuted). //Quirk et al label _have to_ a semi-auxiliary in 'I have to use crutches ...'./

Comment: There is a reason why the Cambridge dictionary uses this approach. If you adopt the traditional view that auxiliaries are dependents of the following "main verb," then in "You ought to leave," "to leave" is not a constituent but "ought to" is.

Comment: That's not true. Even in the trad view, the dependent of the following lexical verb is just the auxiliary "ought", not "ought to". "To" is always part of the following clause, where it functions as a marker. "Ought to" is not a constituent in any grammar. For most speakers, the modal auxiliary "ought" takes a _to_ infinitival clause as complement, though some allow a bare infinitival.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The alternative analysis, as you put it, does not say that "to" is part of the modal verb. It simply says that the auxiliary is a dependent of the following lexical verb, which in this case is "ought". Users of ELU are expected to have a good working knowledge of the basics of English grammar, including knowing that "to" is a subordinator introducing the VP of an infinitival clause. They shouldn't need references for such an elementary point of grammar. I suspect that ZAN is not a grammarian, lest they wouldn't be relying on dictionaries for grammar -- always a fatal error!

Comment: ACGEL 3.41 << Marginal modals: _dare, need, ought to_ and _used to_.... [T]he marginal modals are verbs which closely resemble the central modal auxiliaries. >>

Comment: @BillJ I am proudly not a registered grammarian.  You apparently are not grammarian enough to have uncovered the passage Mr. Ashworth cites. Do you still insist "ought to" is not a marginal modal?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, come on now! ACGEL has been proved wrong about many things. This appears to be one of them.

Comment: Listen up, @Zan 700. The structure of "ought to have been named" is "ought" + to have been named". The classification of "to" has no bearing on whether or not "ought is a marginal modal. "To" is a subordinator introducing the infinitival clause. Have you never heard of a _to_-infinitval clause? And if you're not a grammarian, why are you posting an answer about grammar?

Comment: @BillJ "Registered." If you replace "ought to" with "should" the sentence reads "She gifted the man a dog (,) who should (ought to) have been named."  There is a bare infinitival in that clause, not a full infinitival, as in "He wants to buy a pig." The bare infinitival does not need your blessed subordinator. As you note, ACGEL has been wrong about many things, perhaps, too, a contributor with great self-regard. Don't wave your finger at me, miss!

Comment: 'A reference is hardly needed for something that is as clear as day.' when grammarians as respected as Quirk, Greenbaum, Leech and Svartvik have voiced an opposing view. Unscholarly. At the very least, a referenced answer showing why there is a claimed better analysis would be expected in academic circles.